# How Github Link Anchor Works

Tags: html, anchor

Both links with following anchor-ed a tags:

```
<a id="user-content-cd" class="anchor" aria-hidden="true" href="#cd"></a>
```

Why Github works with `#cd` (Jump to H2 of `cd` section): https://github.com/mitnk/cicada/blob/master/docs/builtins.md#cd

But this one does not work: https://hugo.wang/cicada/builtins.md#cd

??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<a href="#cd">...</a>` links to an element with `id="cd"`.

You need to have a matching element to link to.

Comment: The anchor on GitHub actually links to this element `<a id="user-content-cd" class="anchor" aria-hidden="true" href="#cd">...</a>` which has an entirely different ID.

Comment: They've got a bunch of obfuscated JavaScript. It's probably something to do with that. There's no reason to use JS instead of plain HTML for that though.

Answer (score 0):

It is related to how GitHub prefixes the id of a heading in order to guard against user content clobbering elements used by CSS or JavaScript, see [here](https://github.com/gjtorikian/html-pipeline/issues/135#issuecomment-54322489) for a brief explanation related to this.

> then use JavaScript to perform the actual scrolling to user content.